# Is it possible to use constructor injection with a generic type?

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, autofac

I have event handlers that currently have class and method signatures like this:

```
public class MyEventHandler : IIntegrationEventHandler

public void Handle(IntegrationEventintegrationEvent) // IntegrationEvent is the base class
```

What I want to do is this (so that the handler can accept the concrete type):

```
public class MyEventHandler : IIntegrationEventHandler<MyEvent>

public void Handle(MyEvent integrationEvent)
```

In Startup.cs, I did this:

```
services.AddTransient<IIntegrationEventHandler<MyEvent>, MyEventHandler>();
```

The issue is that the service that gets these handlers injected can't use open generics, like this:

```
public MyService(IEnumerable<IIntegrationEventHandler<>> eventHandlers)
            : base(eventHandlers)
```

Specifying the base class doesn't work either:

```
public MyService(IEnumerable<IIntegrationEventHandler<IntegrationEvent>> eventHandlers)
            : base(eventHandlers)
```

That gives me 0 handlers.

The current approach works in that I get all 7 handlers injected. But that means the handler has to accept the base class in its method and then cast it. Not a huge deal, but would be nice if I could have the handler accept the concrete type it cares about. Is this possible?

Comment: `IIntegrationEventHandler<IntegrationEvent>` and `IIntegrationEventHandler<MyEvent>` are two distinct types. Collection types in C# are restricted to single element type. As a result, what you require cannot be done without type casting, regardless of DI. You might be also able to work around this using other approaches such as visitor pattern.

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek Can we not create IEvent interface then all the events derieves from that interface. So that We can say IIntegrationEventHandler<IEvent> generically?

Comment: @NirmalSubedi Yes, you are correct, but such approach is equivalent to using `IIntegrationEventHandler<IntegrationEvent>` which the OP already has and is not happy with due to the need for concrete implementations to accept abstract parameter type (`IntegrationEvent`) and in effect lose compile-time type safety.

Comment: Another thing you could do is to have type helpers, but I'm not sure if it would suit your needs. Something like `public interface IMyEventIntegrationEventHandler : IIntegrationEventHandler<MyEvent>` (did the best I could with the name, but you get the idea). You'd obviously need to register based on this type rather than on the generic interface

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I don't think that would work because then the handlers wouldn't all be registered as the same type and then I couldn't have them available in constructor injection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you request cannot be done directly. C# collections are always bound to a specific item type and that type must be cast if a different type is desired. And `IIntegrationEventHandler<MyEvent>` and `IIntegrationEventHandler<DifferentEvent>` are different types.

As an alternate solution, you could dispatch events through an intermediary (dispatcher) and route them to concrete handler type using reflection and DI. The handlers will be registered with DI with the specific event type they declare to handle. You can also handle multiple types of events with a single handler implementation. The dispatcher will inject a collection of concrete event handlers based on run-time type of the received event directly from `IServiceProvider`.

I have not compiled or tested the following code but it should give you the general idea.

Startup.cs

```csharp
services
    .AddTransient<IIntegrationEventHandler<MyEvent>, MyEventHandler>()
    .AddTransient<IntegrationEventDispatcher>();
```

IntegrationEventDispatcher.cs

```csharp
private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

public IntegrationEventDispatcher(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
}

public void Dispatch(IntegrationEvent @event)
{
    var eventType = @event.GetType();

    // TODO: Possibly cache the below reflected types for improved performance
    var handlerType = typeof(IIntegrationEventHandler<>).MakeGenericType(eventType);
    var handlerCollectionType = typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(handlerType);
    var handlers = (IEnumerable)_serviceProvider.GetService(handlerCollectionType);

    var handleMethod = handlerType.GetMethod("Handle", eventType);

    foreach (var handler in handlers)
    {
        handleMethod.Invoke(handler, new[] { @event });
    }
}
```

MyService.cs

```csharp
// ...

private readonly IntegrationEventDispatcher  _eventDispatcher;

public MyService(IntegrationEventDispatcher eventDispatcher)
{
    _eventDispatcher = eventDispatcher;
}

public void DoStuffAndDispatchEvents()
{
    // ...
    _eventDispatcher.Dispatch(new MyEvent());
    _eventDispatcher.Dispatch(new DifferentEvent());
}
```

---

Edit:

Generics-based dispatcher implementation ([gist](https://gist.github.com/zdenek-jelinek/7c8b5cc0845c96986f2758198c20138a)):

```csharp
public void Dispatch<TEvent>(TEvent @event) where TEvent : IntegrationEvent 
{
    var handlers = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IEnumerable<IIntegrationEventHandler<TEvent>>>();

    foreach (var handler in handlers)
    {
        handler.Handle(@event);
    }
}
```

---

Edit 2:
In order to support event handling from the base type, there are a couple of approaches that come to my mind:

**a) Use the reflection-based approach from above.**

Performance-wise this won't be the best but it will work for any type it will receive.

**b) Use a type switch**

Switch on event type to invoke `Dispatch<T>` with proper type. The downside is that you need to list all supported event types and update the list when any new event type is introduced. Also, this might be somewhat tricky to catch with tests.

The `IntegrationEventDispatcher` logic becomes

```csharp
    public void Dispatch(IntegrationEvent @event)
    {
        switch (@event)
        {
            case MyIntegrationEvent e:
                Dispatch(e); // Calls Dispatch<TEvent> as the overload with a more specific type
                break;

            case OtherIntegrationEvent e:
                Dispatch(e);
                break;

            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException($"Event type {@event.GetType().FullName} not supported.");
        }
    }

    private void Dispatch<TEvent>(TEvent @event) where TEvent : IntegrationEvent
    {
        var handlers = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IEnumerable<IEventHandler<TEvent>>>();

        foreach (var handler in handlers)
        {
            handler.Handle(@event);
        }
    }
```

Gist with a minimal implementation is available [here](https://gist.github.com/zdenek-jelinek/ea0e563240e6e8373c8f4159d3d25e3b).

**c) Use visitor pattern**

Make base event type accept a visitor which visits the concrete event type. This is quite a bit more code and requires changes to the base event type. When new event type is added, it is automatically supported, although a new overload may be necessary if overloads are used instead of generic method (as in proper visitor).

A `IIntegrationEventVisitor` should exist on the same level as `IntegrationEvent` - that may be an architectural issue, however, since events are already designed as objects, I would expect that having a behavior should not be a problem, especially this abstract.

IntegrationEvent.cs

```csharp
public abstract class IntegrationEvent
{
    public abstract void Accept(IIntegrationEventVisitor visitor);
}
```

MyIntegrationEvent.cs

```csharp
public class MyIntegrationEvent : IntegrationEvent
{
    public override void Accept(IIntegrationEventVisitor visitor)
    {
        visitor.Visit(this); // "this" is the concrete type so TEvent is inferred properly
    }
}
```

IIntegrationEventVisitor.cs

```csharp
public interface IIntegrationEventVisitor
{
    // Note: This is not a proper visitor, feel free to implement 
    // overloads for individual concrete event types for proper design.
    // Generic method is not very useful for a visitor in general
    // so this is actually an abstraction leak.
    void Visit<TEvent>(TEvent @event) where TEvent : IntegrationEvent;
}
```

IntegrationEventDispatcher.cs

```csharp
public class IntegrationEventDispatcher : IIntegrationEventVisitor
{
    // Previously known as Dispatch
    public void Visit<TEvent>(TEvent @event) where TEvent : IntegrationEvent
    {
        var handlers = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IEnumerable<IEventHandler<TEvent>>>();

        foreach (var handler in handlers)
        {
            handler.Handle(@event);
        }
    }
}
```

Gist with a minimal implementation is available [here](https://gist.github.com/zdenek-jelinek/b183578e2fd7f1ec2e1a8c21b1c1ea04).

**d) Take a step back**

If you want to dispatch a base type, maybe injecting concrete handlers is not what you need at all and there could be another way.

How about we create an event handler that takes a base type and handles it only if it's relevant? But let's not duplicate these relevance checks in each handler, let's make a class that does it for us in general and delegates to proper handlers.

We will use `IIntegrationEventHandler` as a general handler to accept the base type, implement it with a generic type that checks if the accepted type is relevant and then forwards it to handlers of that type which implement `IIntegrationEventHandler<TEvent>`.

This approach will let you use constructor injection everywhere as you originally requested and generally feels like the closest to your original approach. The downside is that all handlers are instantiated even if they are not used. This could be avoided with e.g. `Lazy<T>` over the concrete handlers collection.

Note that there is no generic `Dispatch` method or any of its variant, you just inject a collection of `IIntegrationEventHandler` where each delegates to collection of `IIntegrationEventHandler<TEvent>` if the received event type is `TEvent`.

IIntegrationEventHandler.cs

```csharp
public interface IIntegrationEventHandler
{
    void Handle(IntegrationEvent @event);
}

public interface IIntegrationEventHandler<TEvent> where TEvent : IntegrationEvent
{
    void Handle(TEvent @event);
}
```

DelegatingIntegrationEventHandler.cs

```csharp
public class DelegatingIntegrationEventHandler<TEvent> : IIntegrationEventHandler where TEvent : IntegrationEvent
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IEventHandler<TEvent>> _handlers;

    public DelegatingIntegrationEventHandler(IEnumerable<IEventHandler<TEvent>> handlers)
    {
        _handlers = handlers;
    }

    public void Handle(IntegrationEvent @event)
    {
        // Check if this event should be handled by this type
        if (!(@event is TEvent concreteEvent))
        {
            return;
        }

        // Forward the event to concrete handlers
        foreach (var handler in _handlers)
        {
            handler.Handle(concreteEvent);
        }
    }
}
```

MyIntegrationEventHandler.cs

```csharp
public class MyIntegrationEventHandler : IIntegrationEventHandler<MyIntegrationEvent>
{
    public void Handle(MyIntegrationEvent @event)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Gist with a minimal implementation is available [here](https://gist.github.com/zdenek-jelinek/8b78f59b55b7253a2770d759a3eca24f). Check it out for actual setup and usage as it is slightly more complex to get it right.

Comment: +1 for the good suggestion. It's interesting that you mention reflection because that's actually the approach I had before. But since these event handlers are going to get hammered with activity, I was looking to get rid of the reflection.

Comment: @BobHorn I have edited the answer with a proposal of generics-based solution. Nevertheless, there will probably be reflection within the DI container to resolve the handlers on each invocation, i.e. I don't expect it to be categorically faster.

Comment: Additionally, you could cache the handlers in the dispatcher (regardless of approach), the downside is that the handlers lifetimes will be extended to that of the dispatcher. This shouldn't be an issue though as, if transient, the dispatcher will inherit the lifetime of its requesting service which is identical to your original approach.

Comment: It took me a while to understand the main point there, but I think I get it now. Instead of constructor injection, and trying to get all the *different* handlers, ask the service provider, at the moment where we have the event, to get the handlers *for just that event*. Does that sound right?

Comment: There may be an issue for me, though. Your example shows an event dispatcher invoking `Dispatch()`. I don't have that luxury. We're putting events on RabbitMQ while using .NET Core CAP.

Comment: @BobHorn You are correct, that is exactly how it works, the handlers resolution from container is deferred until an event is dispatched and then handlers for that specific event type are requested. With regards to `Dispatch`, that is just a generic instance method on a class, just pure C# + IL, all compile-time. There is nothing special going on, no additional frameworks. You might call it whatever you like, especially if another name would make it clearer to you. I don't believe this should limit your integration options with CAP.

Comment: Ah, ok, I think I see now. Let me give that a shot...

Comment: Ok, I don't think I can do this, but I'm willing to accept your answer because it would work for others. In your example, at some point you know the event type. My service doesn't know that. It pulls all events from the queue and treats them as the base class `IntegrationEvent`. At no point do we know the concrete type, and we need to know that to be able to call dispatch with the generic type parameter. I mean, I know the concrete type, but that's only at runtime. At compile time, I can't invoke Dispatch with the correct type.

Comment: @BobHorn I have added some options to do what you require when only base type (`IntegrationEvent`) is available.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I should have a chance to try some of them in the next few days.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I like your last suggestion the best, but I'm not going with it and I wanted to share why in case you have something else to add. The reason is that there is a lot of abstraction/indirection, and I may have gone with it except for the fact that we still have to check the type in the base handler. If we're going to have to check anyway, I'd rather not have the abstraction. Does that make sense?

Comment: Right now my handlers have this: `var specificEvent = integrationEvent as AddEmployeeToPolicyIntegrationEvent;` (and then return if it's null). Yes, each handler has to do it. That's the down side. But I can live with that for now.,

Comment: @BobHorn If you typically have a single handler for each event type, you will only ever write one type check for that event type. Therefore, the indirection is unnecessary and your solution is superior due to it being clearer.